# ранжирование по группам SQL

Tags: sql

Есть таблица следующей структуры:
`client_id, start_dt, end_dt, channel`

мне необходимо в результирующей таблице добавить поле-ранг(возрастающий ключ), который увеличивается для каждого `client_id` при каждой смене `channel`

пример моего sql-запроса:

```
SELECT client_id, start_dt, end_dt, channel,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY channel) AS 'rnk'
FROM Test
```

запрос выдает ранжирование каналов по группам клиентов, но  не могу понять как учесть еще и дату смены `channel`.

Comment: Потребуется два CTE. В первом получите channel текущей и предыдущей записей для клиента по времени, если не сменился, то ноль, иначе один. Во втором CTE выполните оконную SUM() по этому полю - получите нужную нумерацию. Не забудьте учесть, что для первой записи предыдущий channel отсутствует.

Comment: @Akina не обязательно CTE, можно ж просто многоступенчатый запрос. В некоторых БД у CTE есть побочные эффекты.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin *многоступенчатый запрос* Уточните, что имеется в виду. Подзапросы? *В некоторых БД у CTE есть побочные эффекты.* Можно поподробнее? о чём именно речь, о каких побочных эффектах?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, коллеги. Нашел решение, использую конструкции sum() over() для подзапроса case when lead() over() = channel

Comment: @Akina Подзапросы, вложенные запросы `select ... from (select ... from)`. Побочный эффект - материализация, например, которая не всегда желательна. Насколько знаю, в PostreSQL до 12 версии результаты запросов в `with` материализовывались, и потом уже использовались в других частях запроса.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin *Побочный эффект - материализация* Ааа... я уж испугался, что есть случаи, когда может "поплыть" результат.